# Get "Post Count" from public page using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get a **number of posts from a page** in last month. Is is possible with facebook graph API? Also FYI, i just have the **access_token** to interact with the Facebook  API.

Also do anyone knows how to fetch the **number of Page mentions** in last month?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Try using Facebook's Page Insights using Facebook Graph API's :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#page_posts

But please note that you need to be a page admin for this page, and you need to acquire a [Page Access Token with the permissions 'read_insights'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#readpermissions).

If you are not a page admin, then you can also do the same with an [User Access Token or an  App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

Steps:

1. `int postsCount = 0;
2. Use the following API query `https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/posts` and issue a reuquest.
3. Count the posts fetched. `postsCount = postsCount + {the posts json array size}`.
4. Store the cursor returned by the above API result. Use it to fetch the next page of Posts.
5. If the `{the posts json array size} > 0`, then goto step 3.

Notes:

- I am sure that you can do it better with FQL, but I am guessing FQL is being deprecated.
- I think there is a `summary(true)` annotation (`https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}?fields=posts.summary(true)`) that you can use, but I couldn't get it working.
- There is an API rate limit that you need to keep in mind. And do some throttling.

So, the moral of the story is that I am not sure if Facebook really wants you to crawl its Pages if you are not the Admin of the page. :-)

Comment: This is all still accurate today. I just wanted to note to future readers that I was able to get the summary working, but only as described in the [published_posts endpoint docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/published_posts/). So something like: `{page-id}/published_posts?summary=total_count&since=2019-01-01&limit=10`. total_count is unaffected by the limit, and returns the true total for the range specified.

Comment: @ahamilton9 while the endpoint still seem to exist, the total_count is constant at 25 in my case, no matter how I change since or limit field.